# how to use quarkus with other ORM (activejdbc)

Tags: hikaricp, quarkus, activejdbc, agroal

how to use quarkus with other ORM for example, ActiveJdbc framework.because right now hibernate panache doesn't have enough features.

1. I understand that quarkus can have filters, which is useful for opening connections, but how to close the connection or return connection to pool?
2. is quarkus only designed to be good with agroal, can we use hikaricp ?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use native mode, Quarkus is a Java application, and can run all libraries made for Java. However, to use the native mode it is necessary to use the extensions provided by Quarkus.

Comment: or write your own extension https://quarkus.io/guides/writing-extensions